# Google chart controls types gallery

Tags: google-visualization

I'm building dashboard using Google dashboard [link](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls).
I want to use Controls. I found only two of them on the page and only information saying:

> The class name of the control. The google.visualization package name can be omitted for Google controls. Examples: CategoryFilter, NumberRangeFilter.

My question is where can I find other controls types (CategoryFilter, NumberRangeFilter)?
I've searched Internet, including Google for Developers and found only those [examples](http://battlehorse.github.io/google-charts-controls-gallery/), but there is no type names.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Finally I found it.

I found:

- StringFilter
- NumberRangeFilter
- CategoryFilter

and you can style/format them with options:

```
var filter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
'containerId': 'containerId',
'options': {
    'filterColumnLabel': 'Column Label',
    'ui': {
        'allowTyping': false,
        'allowMultiple': true,
        'orientation': 'horizontal',
        'showRangeValues': false,
        'label': ''
    }
}
```

});

And this way you can style/format them the way you want.

Answer (score 2):

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls

under contents menu on the right select 'ChartWrapper';

Controls Gallery

Filters are graphical elements that people can use to interactively select which data is displayed on your chart. This section describes the Google Chart filters: CategoryFilter, ChartRangeFilter, DateRangeFilter, NumberRangeFilter, and StringFilter.